# tramp: $INSIDE_EMACS isn't defined while .bashrc is processed

Tags: tramp

It seems `INSIDE_EMACS` can be used to determine if tramp is used. I know I could use `test "$TERM" = "dumb"` but `if [[ -z $INSIDE_EMACS ]]; then` is provided by the [home-manager](https://github.com/rycee/home-manager) tool.

If I set `tramp-verbose` I can see that `INSIDE_EMACS` is defined in some tramp sessions but it's not when my `.bashrc` is processed. I wonder if `INSIDE_EMACS` could be set after the shell starts.

Any ideas?

GNU Emacs 28.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.14, cairo version 1.16.0)

> Determining a TRAMP session
>
> ```
> Sometimes, it is needed to identify whether a shell runs under TRAMP control. The setting of environment variable TERM will help:
>
> if test "$TERM" = "dumb"; then
>    ...
> fi
>
> Another possibility is to check the environment variable INSIDE_EMACS. Like for all subprocesses of Emacs, this is set to the
> ```
>
> version of the parent Emacs process, See (emacs)Interactive Shell.
>   TRAMP adds its own package version to this string, which could be used
>   for further tests in an inferior shell. The string of that environment
>   variable looks always like
>
> ```
> echo $INSIDE_EMACS
> ⇒ 26.2,tramp:2.3.4
> ```

https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/

**.bashrc**

```
if [[ -z $INSIDE_EMACS ]]; then
  eval "$(/nix/store/ni6mmldfii7mljhnism2rn0pwchr2fmz-starship-0.40.1/bin/starship init bash)"
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$INSIDE_EMACS` is set when the remote shell is called explicitly. However, this is not given when your login shell is called, due to the `ssh` command. Therefore, if you have `bash` as login shell, that variable is not set yet at this time.

Comment: Thank you very much.