# How to run initialization commands with tramp?

Tags: tramp, ess, bash

I would like to run some commands on remote host before giving control to tramp.

E.g., I would like to load [easybuild](https://easybuild.io/) modules to make sure that environment variables are set correctly for ESS.

My understanding is that tramp [doesn't read](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/58023/17055) `.bashrc` by default. Usage of `RemoteCommand` is also [discouraged](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Remote-shell-setup.html).

Is there a way to do this?

The other alternative would be to tweak behaviour of ESS in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the Tramp manual:

```
Setting the ‘ENV’ environment variable instructs some shells to read an initialization file.
By default, TRAMP disables this.  You can override this behavior by evaluating

 (let ((process-environment tramp-remote-process-environment))
   (setenv "ENV" "$HOME/.profile")
   (setq tramp-remote-process-environment process-environment))
```

Comment: Thanks, another problem was that tramp overwrites remote `$PATH`. To fix this I added `(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path 'tramp-own-remote-path)`.